# AMQP transfer frame refused

Tags: linux, frame, amqp

I am currently trying to develop my driver to an ActiveMQ via AMQP 1.0
I could successfully open, begin a session, attach links to this session but my first transfer frame is refused with "error decoding" although wireshark sees it as valid frame as shown in screenshot [wireshark view of transfer frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlUQt.png)

returned frame is a close with Error condition: amqp:decode-error,
Description is Could not decode AMQP frame: hex: ...

Comment: What is the relationship with Ada ? Could you provide more information and if possible textual information instead of pictures ?

Comment: No relation with Ada although my code is written in Ada. I was confused by the request to add several topics. The important point is that I directly generate the frames without passing via an external library. I inserted the wireshark view because it is the only clear view I have upon the frame I generated and its data fields, byte per byte. The issue is that this frame seems to be perfectly valid, at least for wireshark parser, but is actually refused by AMQP. And I don't understand why. Error code amqp:decode-error is not very usable. I suspect that wireshark parsing is not complete

Comment: If I understand the wireshark image it looks like the message length field is 63 while the payload is 8 bytes (64 bits). Could this be the decoding issue?

Comment: AMQP frame (illustrated in grey by wireshark) is 63 bytes, so does not seem to be that. Furthemore, wireshark correctly decodes the arguments until Message-id. I suspect more some wrong encapsulation of the payload itself, or a missing compulsory application-properties not detected by wireshark. I did not find a lot of information about that. I used list-item of 8 bytes for the payload.

Comment: @François, you could please post on-topic snippets of your Ada source code.  •That• would justify (at least a little bit) the Ada tag.

Comment: @Andreas. Source was only at prototype level and had really little interest in this case. I now better understand the logic behind tags, so I just removed Ada from them. Hope you understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see in the encoding you have created a Transfer around a message indicated to be format = 0 which requires a body section of, one AmqpValue, N AmqpSequence sections or N Data sections.  Your encoding seems to encode a Binary as the body section which is incorrect and this is probably where the broker fires off the exception.

The specification outlines this requirement pretty well
http://docs.oasis-open.org/amqp/core/v1.0/os/amqp-core-messaging-v1.0-os.html#section-message-format

Comment: You're probably right. Thank you. I will try to correct this into a data section (next week) instead of a list of binary data, but I must admit I had issues to understand this spec from the first time.

Comment: The spec is very clear on this point, each Binary you want to encode into the body must be wrapped in a Data section.

Comment: I now correctly encapsulated the message data inside a data section. (wireshark reported it correctly), but the problem persists. ActiveMQ rtraces the same error, without any details. I will try to obtain a copy of a transfer frame generated by a java client so as to compare with mine.Thank you for your help.

Comment: Without more information it is difficult to help.  I would suggest capturing a trace from your own client of the outgoing frame bytes in an easy to view manner so that we can see what might be wrong

Comment: Thank you all. I could obtain some local help including the copy of a valid Transfer frame. I am currently busy analysing the valid messages. I will make new attempts (after returning from holidays) and will report my results.

Comment: Ideally you should mark this as answered and ask a new question if additional issues arise